# Nuxt auth with keycloak: ssr this.$auth.loggedIn always false on page load

Tags: authentication, nuxt.js, keycloak, server-side-rendering

I have a setup with nuxt and keycloak as auth strategy which in general is working. I can login via keycloak and then will have `this.$auth.loggedIn === true` on the page. When navigating via vue-router, `this.$auth.loggedIn` will also be true when switching to a new page.

But when I then reload the page (CMD+r/F5), server side rendering will have `false` for `this.$auth.loggedIn`, while on client side it will be `true`. This forced me to do a lot of `<client-only>` blocks in the templates to prevent ssr mismatches.

I wonder if it is possible that on first page load server side rendering can return a page with authorized content? I would think this should be possible since cookies with auth info are set and sent to the server.
Or is that never possible and efficient server side rendering can only be used for non-authorized content?

Versions:

- nuxt: 2.15.8
- @nuxtjs/auth-next: 5.0.0-1643791578.532b3d6

nuxt.config.js:

```
auth: {
  strategies: {
    keycloak: {
      scheme: 'oauth2',
      endpoints: {
        authorization: `${ process.env.KEYCLOAK }/protocol/openid-connect/auth`,
        userInfo: `${ process.env.KEYCLOAK }/protocol/openid-connect/userinfo`,
        token: `${ process.env.KEYCLOAK }/protocol/openid-connect/token`,
        logout: `${ process.env.KEYCLOAK }/protocol/openid-connect/logout`,
      },
      token: {
        property: 'access_token',
        type: 'Bearer',
        maxAge: 1800,
      },
      refreshToken: {
        property: 'refresh_token',
        maxAge: 60 * 60 * 24 * 30,
      },
      responseType: 'code',
      grantType: 'authorization_code',
      clientId: process.env.CLIENT_ID,
      scope: ['openid', 'profile', 'email', 'roles'],
      codeChallengeMethod: 'S256',
      redirect: {
        logout: '/',
        callback: '/',
        home: '/',
      },
    },
  },
},
```

Having a Vue component with this:

```
created() {
  console.log(this.$auth.loggedIn);
},
```

Will return `false` for SSR and `true` on client side on page load/refresh when logged in.

Comment: I'm pretty sure I've achieved exactly the same. Where do you login? I've used a global middleware.

Comment: I have a button that calls `this.$auth.loginWith('keycloak')` which opens the keycloak login page. After login, keycloak is configured to redirect back to the page.

Comment: Keycloak do open a new tab or moves you to that page before bringing you back to your app? Checking if the token is available in a middleware is probably a good solution anyway. Also, you can probably use an AJAX call to proceed on your webapp rather than letting yourself redirected. I worked in a homemade JWT token where I was storing my auth token in the cookie and never had an issue when refreshing either with `static` or `server` as a `target` value.

Comment: My site redirects to keycloak for login and keycloak redirects me back afterwards. But I'm not sure if how I login is relevant to my problem, since this occurs while successfully logged in. So your suggestion is to write a middleware that on first page load will parse the cookies and do a manual check with the keycloak server if the user is logged in? I might try that then sometime, thanks!

Comment: Yep, exactly that!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After manually implementing a server side authenticator, I found out that the problem was my local docker setup.

Didn't think this was the problem before, so I forgot to mention it.
I have a local docker container with keycloak and a local docker container with nuxt.

Long story short, it seems that the nuxt server wasn't able to communicate with keycloak, hence wasn't able to fetch the user. After changing some addresses so that keycloak was available on the same address from the browser and from within my nuxt server docker container, the nuxt server did get $auth.loggedIn=true automatically on page load if the is was logged in.

Not sure if I didn't see it, but I wished nuxt auth would give me an error if the nuxt server failed to communicate with the authorization server. Would have saved me a lot of debugging.